# How do we know physical address of memory page containing instructions if not in RAM yet?

Tags: memory-management, cpu, cpu-architecture, tlb

I am a little confused in terms of how the instructions of a process are executed, due to the chicken & egg analogy.

The CPU instructions of a program are saved on hard disk. When the program goes to execute, the page of memory containing the instructions needs to go to RAM, L3, L2, L1i. However, how can the physical address be known, to load it to RAM when we can only find out the physical address after a TLB look-up, which means the instructions must already be in the L1i cache?

Comment: Do you mean to ask "how does the internal algorithm of CPU memory management work"? Sounds to me like a know-how

Comment: The CPU instructions are saved on hard disk. When the program goes to execute, the page of memory containing the instructions needs to go to RAM, L3, L2, L1i. However, how can the physical address be known, to load it to RAM when we can only find out the physical address after a TLB look-up, which means the instructions must already be in the L1i cache? (and obviously we know they aren't)

Comment: It is not entirely clear if you are asking about system bootstrapping or program loading. For program loading, the OS (and so its file system code) is already loaded into memory and the appropriate parts of the page table established. For bootstrapping address translation is turned on after a minimal page table has been set up.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton program loading. so how is the correct page physical address given to the cpu?

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton could you possibly elaborate on the program loading? I understand the OS contains a page table, so are you saying if I execute myprogram.exe, the OS will look this up the physical address of the first memory page for that program?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter. The OS just picks a free page, using whatever mechanism it likes.

Comment: How can it not matter? :s

Comment: @user3811839: Because the OS also sets up the physical to virtual address translation. So, assuming Windows pre-Vista, it would pick a random physical address X to load your program, and then map X to virtual address 00400000. And the CPU understands what happens when the OS sets up a physical-to-virtual translation in the page table. BTW, note that a cache (including TLB) is an optimization. All caches miss thigns, hopefully the infrequently used things.

Comment: Would you be able to point me towards something where I can read more about this? What is this called?

Comment: is this the "loader"?